# iTMSTransporter fails with error -20101

Tags: ios, xml, macos, command-line, app-store-connect

I've received an email from Apple yesterday stating that it's now possible to deliver App Store metadata localizations using a command-line tool called Transporter.

I've downloaded iTunes_Store_Transporter_Quick_Start_Guide_v2.pdf from iTunes Connect and followed the example for a simple lookup of the metadata of an app:

```
To initiate lookup mode, use the following command:
$ iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u [iTunes Connect user name]
                  -p [iTunes Connect password] -vendor_id [App SKU]
                  -destination [destination path for App Store Package]
```

However, although my login credentials and all other informations entered are correct, I always receive the following error:

```
[2013-07-19 14:34:40 MESZ] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Errors = [Directory Services reported the following error: Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly. (-20101)]
[2013-07-19 14:34:40 MESZ] <main> ERROR: Apple's web service operation was not successful
[2013-07-19 14:34:40 MESZ] <main> ERROR: An error occurred while looking up the metadata.
[2013-07-19 14:34:40 MESZ] <main> ERROR: Directory Services reported the following error: Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly. (-20101)
[2013-07-19 14:34:40 MESZ] <main> DBG-X: The error code is: -20101
```

INFOS: My password contains special characters. Thus I've tried to pass the password with and without quotation marks.

Comment: Could somebody with 1500+ reputation please create and add the tag 'itmstransporter'? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Tafkadasoh It's the dollar sign that's causing the problem. Since the $ character is reserved for different kind of variables in unix, you have to escape it.

Instead of

```
-p 'Pass$123'
```

Use

```
-p 'Pass\$123'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I'm not working as an iOS dev anymore, so I can't test it. But hey, you might be right, as my pw included a $ sign...

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using and what are the special characters that your password contains? If you're using OS X try it with single quotes, e.g. `'password'` not `"password"`.

If you're going to be using `iTMSTransporter` a lot I would recommend
[using this program](https://github.com/sshaw/itunes_store_transporter#using-itms).

Comment: Single quotes didn't work either, but thanks for the suggestion. I'm using Mac OS 10.8.4 and iTMSTransporter version 1.7.8.1. And my password contains '$' characters.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, it worked for me to remove the password parameter. iTMSTransporter will then ask for password entry on the command-line. This isn't a real solution, as you can't use this for automated scripts (for which iTMSTransporter is intended to use for). For infrequent use however, this might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

@Tafkadasoh - that workaround worked great for me too, I can now connect and grab the metadata package.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Tracedog, welcome at StackOverflow! I'm glad my workaround helped you. Please notice however that answers at StackOverflow should only include information that help to solve the original question of the post. For other infos, I use comments, which unfortunately require 50 [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). And those should be used [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Reputation gives you [certain priviledges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Getting 1st privileges takes some time, but please keep contributing meaningful posts.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD` and `FASTLANE_PASSWORD` in my environment variables. So I remove `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD` and it worked.

If you have `FASTLANE_SESSION` along with `FASTLANE_PASSWORD`, you may need to remove `FASTLANE_SESSION`.